# Can you return multiple pages of a query at once in Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have query that returns 25000 documents from Cosmos DB.

Currently I do it like:

```
 FeedOptions feedOptions = new FeedOptions();
  feedOptions.MaxItemCount = -1;
  feedOptions.EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true;
  var result = new List<ProductDocument>();
  var documentQuery = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<ProductDocument>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, _collectionName), feedOptions)
    .Where(p => p.CompanyId == companyId);
```

However this gets in batches of around 375 documents, so takes a while.
What I would like to do is fetch 10 pages at a time (so I would get around 3750 ish each time).  I don't miond increasing RU to support this, however I can't find a way to achieve this at all.

Is it possible?  Or is there another way to return a lot of documents efficiently?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are seeing regarding "takes a while", and what your goal is? The query result contains metrics about how many RU you query takes and how long to execute, so you can determine the throughput needed to meet a goal.

Comment: The problem is that we have to request the documents sequentially right now, so no matter what we set the throughput too, each document request pulls back 375 documents and takes a bit of time.  So this all adds up to 66 seperate requests which can take 1 min or more.  What I would like is to do 10 requests at a time, so it does it in a tenth of the time effectively.  I am looking at putting a filter on so different requets can get Ids that start with 'a' and 'b' in parallel, but it seems a massive fudge